# Reduction of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

My problem seems very simple, however I couldn't find its solution. Hope someone can help here. I have a list including 189 rows (and 2 columns) as follows:

```
mat={{5.1, -0.414603}, {5.2, -0.418543}, {5.3, -0.422344}, {5.4, \
-0.426015}, {5.5, -0.429562}, {5.6, -0.432994}, {5.7, -0.436316}, \
{5.8, -0.439536}, {5.9, -0.442658}, {6., -0.445688}, {6.1, \
-0.448631}, {6.2, -0.451491}, {6.3, -0.454274}, {6.4, -0.456982}, \
{6.5, -0.459619}, {6.6, -0.462190}, {6.7, -0.464698}, {6.8, \
-0.467145}, {6.9, -0.469534}, {7., -0.471869}, {7.1, -0.474152}, \
{7.2, -0.476385}, {7.3, -0.478571}, {7.4, -0.480711}, {7.5, \
-0.482809}, {7.6, -0.484866}, {7.7, -0.486883}, {7.8, -0.488862}, \
{7.9, -0.490806}, {8., -0.492716}, {8.1, -0.494593}, {8.2, \
-0.496438}, {8.3, -0.498254}, {8.4, -0.500040}, {8.5, -0.501800}, \
{8.6, -0.503533}, {8.7, -0.505240}, {8.8, -0.506924}, {8.9, \
-0.508584}, {9., -0.510222}, {9.1, -0.511839}, {9.2, -0.513436}, \
{9.3, -0.515013}, {9.4, -0.516572}, {9.5, -0.518112}, {9.6, \
-0.519635}, {9.7, -0.521142}, {9.8, -0.522633}, {9.9, -0.524108}, \
{10., -0.525569}, {10.1, -0.527016}, {10.2, -0.528450}, {10.3, \
-0.529871}, {10.4, -0.531280}, {10.5, -0.532677}, {10.6, -0.534062}, \
{10.7, -0.535437}, {10.8, -0.536801}, {10.9, -0.538155}, {11., \
-0.539500}, {11.1, -0.540836}, {11.2, -0.542163}, {11.3, -0.543482}, \
{11.4, -0.544792}, {11.5, -0.546095}, {11.6, -0.547391}, {11.7, \
-0.548680}, {11.8, -0.549962}, {11.9, -0.551238}, {12., -0.552507}, \
{12.1, -0.553771}, {12.2, -0.555030}, {12.3, -0.556283}, {12.4, \
-0.557531}, {12.5, -0.558775}, {12.6, -0.560014}, {12.7, -0.561248}, \
{12.8, -0.562479}, {12.9, -0.563706}, {13., -0.564929}, {13.1, \
-0.566149}, {13.2, -0.567366}, {13.3, -0.568580}, {13.4, -0.569791}, \
{13.5, -0.570999}, {13.6, -0.572205}, {13.7, -0.573409}, {13.8, \
-0.574610}, {13.9, -0.575810}, {14., -0.577008}, {14.1, -0.578204}, \
{14.2, -0.579399}, {14.3, -0.580592}, {14.4, -0.581784}, {14.5, \
-0.582975}, {14.6, -0.584165}, {14.7, -0.585355}, {14.8, -0.586543}, \
{14.9, -0.587731}, {15., -0.588919}, {15.1, -0.590106}, {15.2, \
-0.591293}, {15.3, -0.592480}, {15.4, -0.593667}, {15.5, -0.594855}, \
{15.6, -0.596042}, {15.7, -0.597230}, {15.8, -0.598418}, {15.9, \
-0.599606}, {16., -0.600795}, {16.1, -0.601985}, {16.2, -0.603176}, \
{16.3, -0.604367}, {16.4, -0.605560}, {16.5, -0.606753}, {16.6, \
-0.607948}, {16.7, -0.609143}, {16.8, -0.610340}, {16.9, -0.611539}, \
{17., -0.612738}, {17.1, -0.613940}, {17.2, -0.615142}, {17.3, \
-0.616347}, {17.4, -0.617553}, {17.5, -0.618760}, {17.6, -0.619970}, \
{17.7, -0.621181}, {17.8, -0.622394}, {17.9, -0.623609}, {18., \
-0.624826}, {18.1, -0.626045}, {18.2, -0.627267}, {18.3, -0.628490}, \
{18.4, -0.629716}, {18.5, -0.630944}, {18.6, -0.632174}, {18.7, \
-0.633406}, {18.8, -0.634641}, {18.9, -0.635878}, {19., -0.637117}, \
{19.1, -0.638360}, {19.2, -0.639605}, {19.3, -0.640853}, {19.4, \
-0.642104}, {19.5, -0.643360}, {19.6, -0.644618}, {19.7, -0.645880}, \
{19.8, -0.647146}, {19.9, -0.648415}, {20., -0.649687}, {20.1, \
-0.650963}, {20.2, -0.652240}, {20.3, -0.653520}, {20.4, -0.654802}, \
{20.5, -0.656086}, {20.6, -0.657372}, {20.7, -0.658661}, {20.8, \
-0.659953}, {20.9, -0.661248}, {21., -0.662546}, {21.1, -0.663847}, \
{21.2, -0.665151}, {21.3, -0.666460}, {21.4, -0.667774}, {21.5, \
-0.669093}, {21.6, -0.670418}, {21.7, -0.671748}, {21.8, -0.673082}, \
{21.9, -0.674416}, {22., -0.675746}, {22.1, -0.677070}, {22.2, \
-0.678384}, {22.3, -0.679689}, {22.4, -0.680986}, {22.5, -0.682282}, \
{22.6, -0.683584}, {22.7, -0.684898}, {22.8, -0.686228}, {22.9, \
-0.687573}, {23., -0.688930}, {23.1, -0.690294}, {23.2, -0.691663}, \
{23.3, -0.693041}, {23.4, -0.694431}, {23.5, -0.695841}, {23.6, \
-0.697274}, {23.7, -0.698732}, {23.8, -0.700217}, {23.9, -0.701731}}
```

For some reasons, I want to extract just 70 equally distributed rows from it so that the new list has 70 rows and still 2 columns. I can select some parts of this list using `Table` for example s follows:

```
newlist = 
  Table[{mat[[i, 1]], mat[[i, 2]]}, {i, 1, Length[mat] - 3, 3}];
```

But it has 63 rows, and there is no way to produce a list with exactly 70 rows. I took a look at some commands such as `Case`, `Take`, `Select` and `Extract` but none can't solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `Subdivide` and `Floor` to get 70 *reasonably* equally distributed row values to extract?

```
Floor@Subdivide[1,189,69]

(* 
   {1, 3, 6, 9, 11, 14, 17, 20, 22, 25, 28, 30, 33, 36, 39, 41, 44, 
   47, 50, 52, 55, 58, 60, 63, 66, 69, 71, 74, 77, 80, 82, 85, 88, 90,
   93, 96, 99, 101, 104, 107,109, 112, 115, 118, 120, 123, 126, 129,
   131, 134, 137, 139, 142, 145, 148, 150, 153, 156, 159, 161, 164, 
   167, 169, 172, 175, 178, 180, 183, 186, 189}
*)
```

These values may be used (i) in  conjunction with [Part](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)

```
extractedOne = mat[[Floor@Subdivide[1,189,69]]];
```

Or, (ii) with [Extract](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html)

```
extractedTwo = Extract[mat,Transpose[{Floor@Subdivide[1,189,69]}]]
```

And:

```
Short[extractedOne]
Length[extractedOne]
extractedOne == extractedTwo

(* 
  {5.1, -0.414603}, {5.3, -0.422344}, <<67>>, {23.9, -0.701731}} 

  70

  True
*)
```

(In the `Extract` method, `Transpose[{list}]` is used merely to transform the list of rows into a form suitable for `Extract`)

```
Transpose[{Floor@Subdivide[1,189,69]}] //Short

Transpose[{Floor@Subdivide[1,189,69]}]== List/@Floor@Subdivide[3,189,69]

(* 
  {{1}, {3}, {6}, {9}, {11}, {14}, {17}, <<60>>, {183}, {186}, {189}} 
  True
*)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this method changes the original data, see second row in your result which is obviously different with corresponding row in `mat`. As I'm working with 8 decimal places, I need a method to recover 8 decimal places of `mat` at least.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I was wrong, and `Intersection[new, mat]` clarifies everything. Thanks a lot. I think the method works... Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: @Wisdom I have added some explanation (along with `Part` method)

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

mat = {{5.1, -0.414603}, {5.2, -0.418543}, {5.3, -0.422344}, {5.4, \
-0.426015}, {5.5, -0.429562}, {5.6, -0.432994}, {5.7, -0.436316}, \
{5.8, -0.439536}, {5.9, -0.442658}, {6., -0.445688}, {6.1, \
-0.448631}, {6.2, -0.451491}, {6.3, -0.454274}, {6.4, -0.456982}, \
{6.5, -0.459619}, {6.6, -0.462190}, {6.7, -0.464698}, {6.8, \
-0.467145}, {6.9, -0.469534}, {7., -0.471869}, {7.1, -0.474152}, \
{7.2, -0.476385}, {7.3, -0.478571}, {7.4, -0.480711}, {7.5, \
-0.482809}, {7.6, -0.484866}, {7.7, -0.486883}, {7.8, -0.488862}, \
{7.9, -0.490806}, {8., -0.492716}, {8.1, -0.494593}, {8.2, \
-0.496438}, {8.3, -0.498254}, {8.4, -0.500040}, {8.5, -0.501800}, \
{8.6, -0.503533}, {8.7, -0.505240}, {8.8, -0.506924}, {8.9, \
-0.508584}, {9., -0.510222}, {9.1, -0.511839}, {9.2, -0.513436}, \
{9.3, -0.515013}, {9.4, -0.516572}, {9.5, -0.518112}, {9.6, \
-0.519635}, {9.7, -0.521142}, {9.8, -0.522633}, {9.9, -0.524108}, \
{10., -0.525569}, {10.1, -0.527016}, {10.2, -0.528450}, {10.3, \
-0.529871}, {10.4, -0.531280}, {10.5, -0.532677}, {10.6, -0.534062}, \
{10.7, -0.535437}, {10.8, -0.536801}, {10.9, -0.538155}, {11., \
-0.539500}, {11.1, -0.540836}, {11.2, -0.542163}, {11.3, -0.543482}, \
{11.4, -0.544792}, {11.5, -0.546095}, {11.6, -0.547391}, {11.7, \
-0.548680}, {11.8, -0.549962}, {11.9, -0.551238}, {12., -0.552507}, \
{12.1, -0.553771}, {12.2, -0.555030}, {12.3, -0.556283}, {12.4, \
-0.557531}, {12.5, -0.558775}, {12.6, -0.560014}, {12.7, -0.561248}, \
{12.8, -0.562479}, {12.9, -0.563706}, {13., -0.564929}, {13.1, \
-0.566149}, {13.2, -0.567366}, {13.3, -0.568580}, {13.4, -0.569791}, \
{13.5, -0.570999}, {13.6, -0.572205}, {13.7, -0.573409}, {13.8, \
-0.574610}, {13.9, -0.575810}, {14., -0.577008}, {14.1, -0.578204}, \
{14.2, -0.579399}, {14.3, -0.580592}, {14.4, -0.581784}, {14.5, \
-0.582975}, {14.6, -0.584165}, {14.7, -0.585355}, {14.8, -0.586543}, \
{14.9, -0.587731}, {15., -0.588919}, {15.1, -0.590106}, {15.2, \
-0.591293}, {15.3, -0.592480}, {15.4, -0.593667}, {15.5, -0.594855}, \
{15.6, -0.596042}, {15.7, -0.597230}, {15.8, -0.598418}, {15.9, \
-0.599606}, {16., -0.600795}, {16.1, -0.601985}, {16.2, -0.603176}, \
{16.3, -0.604367}, {16.4, -0.605560}, {16.5, -0.606753}, {16.6, \
-0.607948}, {16.7, -0.609143}, {16.8, -0.610340}, {16.9, -0.611539}, \
{17., -0.612738}, {17.1, -0.613940}, {17.2, -0.615142}, {17.3, \
-0.616347}, {17.4, -0.617553}, {17.5, -0.618760}, {17.6, -0.619970}, \
{17.7, -0.621181}, {17.8, -0.622394}, {17.9, -0.623609}, {18., \
-0.624826}, {18.1, -0.626045}, {18.2, -0.627267}, {18.3, -0.628490}, \
{18.4, -0.629716}, {18.5, -0.630944}, {18.6, -0.632174}, {18.7, \
-0.633406}, {18.8, -0.634641}, {18.9, -0.635878}, {19., -0.637117}, \
{19.1, -0.638360}, {19.2, -0.639605}, {19.3, -0.640853}, {19.4, \
-0.642104}, {19.5, -0.643360}, {19.6, -0.644618}, {19.7, -0.645880}, \
{19.8, -0.647146}, {19.9, -0.648415}, {20., -0.649687}, {20.1, \
-0.650963}, {20.2, -0.652240}, {20.3, -0.653520}, {20.4, -0.654802}, \
{20.5, -0.656086}, {20.6, -0.657372}, {20.7, -0.658661}, {20.8, \
-0.659953}, {20.9, -0.661248}, {21., -0.662546}, {21.1, -0.663847}, \
{21.2, -0.665151}, {21.3, -0.666460}, {21.4, -0.667774}, {21.5, \
-0.669093}, {21.6, -0.670418}, {21.7, -0.671748}, {21.8, -0.673082}, \
{21.9, -0.674416}, {22., -0.675746}, {22.1, -0.677070}, {22.2, \
-0.678384}, {22.3, -0.679689}, {22.4, -0.680986}, {22.5, -0.682282}, \
{22.6, -0.683584}, {22.7, -0.684898}, {22.8, -0.686228}, {22.9, \
-0.687573}, {23., -0.688930}, {23.1, -0.690294}, {23.2, -0.691663}, \
{23.3, -0.693041}, {23.4, -0.694431}, {23.5, -0.695841}, {23.6, \
-0.697274}, {23.7, -0.698732}, {23.8, -0.700217}, {23.9, -0.701731}};
```

Interpolate and resample the data.

```
f = Interpolation[mat];

mat2 = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 5.1, 23.9, (23.9 - 5.1)/69}];

Dimensions@mat2

(* {70, 2} *)
```

**EDIT:**

End values plus random sampling:

```
mat3 = Join[mat[[{1, -1}]], RandomChoice[mat[[2 ;; -2]], 
  68]] // Sort;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does `Interpolation` change my initial data? Or just return the same? As I understand, it just a trick to work with non-integer steps in Table, right?

Comment: The interpolation does not change your original data. However, very few of your original data points appear in the resampled data (only the first and last). Look at `Intersection[mat, mat2]` and `ListPlot[{mat, mat2}]`

Comment: Oh, bad news! I look for a way that doesn't change anything in my initial data, Is there such a way?

Comment: As @bmf suggested, take any 70 consecutive values, e.g., `mat[[n ;; n+69]]`; or every other value, e.g., `mat[[n ;; 139 + n ;; 2]]`

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in the question, I need rows from the all range of my data.

Comment: You also said they need to be equally distributed. You have mutually exclusive criteria.

Comment: Yes, that is what I need